# Error trying to push a comit to a GitHub Organization

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I'm getting the following error while trying to push a commit to a github organization, that I have just been added, using the command "git push --set-upstream origin

```
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
ERROR: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried pushing a commit to another repository, which is personal and does not belong to the previously mentioned organization, and it worked, so I don't belive that the problem lies with the SSH key that I'm using on my machine

I tried checking on my GitHub page if my SSH key is properly configured for my current machine, and it's

I cloned a repository from the organization, created a new branch, made some changes and committed, and when I tried to push it I got an error

Answer (score 1):

The message `ERROR: Write access to repository not granted` indicates that you do not have permission to write to the given repository.

You were able to clone it because you probably have read access.

Comment: That was the problem, my boss gave me reading access instead of editor. Thank you!